# Facebook Like Button Frontpage As The FacebookPage

Tags: facebook

Our Facebook-page (on facebook.com itself) has a number of likes.
Our website index page has another number of likes.

i want to create the like button on the index-page that shows the number of likes of our facebook-page.

is this possible, i can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the like box plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ might be what you want

Comment: thanx, this answer is usefull

Comment: cool, do you think you could accept it then. It's how this site works